# Gtk2::SimpleList's boolean column: how to capture signals?

Tags: perl, gtk

How do I capture the toggling of a boolean toggle checkbox in Gtk2::SimpleList?

I understand the checkbox itself is a Gtk2::CellRendererToggle, which emits a `toggled` signal, but how do I access it and set a signal handler?

How do I even capture data-edited events in the SimpleList widget?

```
use Glib qw(TRUE FALSE);
use Gtk2 '-init';
use Gtk2::SimpleList;

my $slist = Gtk2::SimpleList->new(
    'Bool Field'    => 'bool',
    'Text Field'    => 'text'
);
$slist->set_column_editable(1, TRUE);

@{$slist->{data}} = (
    [ TRUE, 'text' ],
    [ FALSE, 'more text' ]
);

my $window = Gtk2::Window->new;
$window->set_border_width(8);
$window->signal_connect(destroy => sub { exit(0); });
$window->add($slist);
$window->show_all;

Gtk2->main;
```

Answer (score 0):

After diving to SimpleList.pm, I conjured up the code below which seems to work. It's not very intuitive though.

```
# bool column
my $col = $slist->get_column(0);
my $r = $col->get_cell_renderers;
$r->signal_connect(toggled => sub {
    my ($widget, $value, $args) = @_;
    print "checkbox toggled to $value\n";
});

# text column
($slist->get_column(1))->get_cell_renderers->signal_connect(
    edited => sub {
        my ($widget, $text_path, $new_text, $args) = @_;
        print "new text is $new_text\n";
    }
);
```